# How to use HTML5 Local Storage with Ember.js?

Tags: html, ember.js, local-storage

I would like to use HTML5 Local Storage with my Ember.js.

I haven't been able to find any examples of doing this without Ember Data.

How should this be done? What do I need to consider?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So let's say we have an object called `Storage` that in our real-world implementation would represent an adapter-like object for the `localStorage` to store and retrieve data:

```
App.Storage = Ember.Object.extend({
  init: function() {
    this.clearStorage();

    var items = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    localStorage.items = JSON.stringify(items);
  },
  find: function(key) {
    // pseudo implementation
    if( !Ember.isNone(key) ) {
      var items = [];
      var storedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
      storedItems.forEach(function(item){
        items.pushObject(item);
      });
      return items;
    }
  },
  clearStorage: function() {
    // pseudo implementation
    localStorage.clear();
  }
});
```

Beside the pseudo implementations, you can see there is a dummy array with some data stored at object initialization, we will use this later in our `IndexRoute` `model` hook to retrieve it, just to show that this works.

Now to the more nice stuff, you could do the `register` & `inject` directly after the application is ready, but what if we wanted it to be already available at application initialization? Well "there an ember-feature for that", called `Application.initializer`, initializer are simple classes with a 'name' property and a `initialize` function in where you have access to your application `container` and do what ever needs to be done, let me explain this in code:

To be notified when the application start loading we can listen to the `onLoad` event to create our initializer classes that will `register` and `inject` the before mentioned `Storage` object into every controller and every route:

```
Ember.onLoad('Ember.Application', function(Application) {
 // Initializer for registering the Storage Object
  Application.initializer({
    name: "registerStorage",
    initialize: function(container, application) {
      application.register('storage:main', application.Storage, {singleton: true});
    }
  });
 // Initializer for injecting the Storage Object
  Application.initializer({
    name: "injectStorage",

    initialize: function(container, application) {
      application.inject('controller', 'storage', 'storage:main');
      application.inject('route', 'storage', 'storage:main');
    }
  });
});
```

Now, since the `Storage` object was injected into every route and every controller we can finally get access to it in our `IndexRoute` `model` hook and make the stores array mentioned above available trough the call `self.get('storage').find('items')` to our template to be rendered (just added a promise to make it actually conform with the ember-way and with some fictive delay, rather than just returning the array):

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    var self = this;
    var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
      Ember.run.later(function() {
        var data = self.get('storage').find('items');
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data);
      }, 1000);
    });

    return promise;
  }
});
```

In our `index` template we can now agnostically loop over the dummy array not caring where it is coming from:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  <h2>Index</h2>
  <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>Item: {{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

And lastly, you can see here all the above explained in a working example: http://jsbin.com/eqAfeP/2/edit

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is great, but I thought I would add this alternative:

Dan Gebhardt has created a very interesting library called [Orbit.js](https://github.com/orbitjs/orbit.js) for coordinating different data sources on a client.  There are three out of the box data sources: memory, local storage, and json api.

For ember integration, check out [ember-orbit](https://github.com/orbitjs/ember-orbit).

It is still under heavy development at this time, and it introduces a different paradigm than [Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data), so proceed with caution!